# serving a static file from a calculated path

Tags: fastify

I have using `@fastify/static v 6.12` to declare two different static paths like so

```
import fastifyStatic from '@fastify/static';

fastify.register(fastifyStatic, {
        root: path.join(cwd(), 'public'),
        prefix: '/public/'
});

fastify.register(fastifyStatic, {
        root: path.join(cwd(), 'data', 'treatments-archive'),
        prefix: '/treatments-archive/',
        decorateReply: false
});
```

It is the second static declaration for which I want to figure out the path based on the requested resource stored in a hierarchical structure. The rule is like so -- if the requested resource is

`http://server/treatments-archive/somefile.xml`

then serve

```
treatments-archive/
    |_ s/
    | |_ so/
    | | |_ som/
    | | | |_ somefile.xml
```

How can I do this? Or would this not be considered suitable for the `static` plugin?